# R: Regex to string detect date-time format in R

Tags: r

What would be a solution to detect date-time format

```
14/07/2009 19:15:29
```

Is this a fullproof solution?

```
str_detect(s,regex("([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}) [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"))
```

For example for the format

```
14.07.2009
```

I have written the regex to be

```
str_detect(date,regex("([0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{4})"))
```

I don't have much idea regarding regex in R or regex in general, just the very basic stuff so would appreciate an easy approach with detailed logic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are several packages, like `lubridate` that try to guess the format of a date.

Comment: Can you provide some useful links?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html

Comment: How to deal with POSIXct format?

Comment: Can it be easily converted to character type?

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner, I sometimes found it helpful to assemble the pattern as follows:

```
c(
  "[0-9]{2}", # day
  "/",
  "[0-9]{2}", # month
  "/",
  "[0-9]{4}", # year
  " ",
  "[0-9]{2}", # Hour
  ":",
  "[0-9]{2}", # minute
  ":",
  "[0-9]{2}"  # second
) |> paste(collapse = "")
```

Returns the pattern:

```
[1] "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"
```

```
stringr::str_detect("14/07/2009 19:15:29",
                    "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}")
# [1] TRUE
```

***Update (as per comments)***

Here is how you could use the `lubridate` package. `dmy_hms()` finds datetimes in your format:

```
lubridate::dmy_hms("14/07/2009 19:15:29")

# [1] "2009-07-14 19:15:29 UTC"
```

But it will not parse invalid dates:

```
lubridate::dmy_hms("14/07/2009 19:15:70") # invalid seconds

# [1] NA
```

So to validate you could do:

```
(! is.na(lubridate::dmy_hms("14/07/2009 19:15:29")))

# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: What about dates which don't exist like 99/99/9999 99:99:99? Won't it return TRUE for all these regexes as well?

Comment: Yes, it would! In order to validate dates I would suggest using an existing package like `lubridate`

Comment: Hi, I went through lubridate package. Can you tell me how to use it in this case?

Comment: If this date type is already in a POSIXct format then it will be already loaded into R in this format **2009-07-14 19:15:29 UTC**. What if the issue is in the Excel file, the date looks like **14-07-2009 19:15:29** and the type is POSIXct?  Then using your code this will also return TRUE but the purpose won't be satisfied

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide us with a reproducible [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) that we can copy and paste to better understand the issue and test possible solutions. You can share datasets with `dput(YOUR_DATASET)` or smaller samples with `dput(head(YOUR_DATASET))`. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610) for some great advice.)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68096002/r-are-there-multiple-posixct-date-formats-and-if-so-how-to-convert-one-posixct?noredirect=1#68096002) will give you a better idea. This question talks about changing the date format. All I am asking you is how to validate in such a scenario? The question could also be looked upon as how to validate whether the date format is in the desired format in the Excel file.

Comment: This is nonsensical: If it's already POSIXct then it's already valid. Without example data and a clear description of what you want to achieve I cannot help you.