# Are there multiple POSIXct date formats and if so how to convert one POSIXct date format to another POSIXct date format in R?

Tags: r

I have an .xlsx file in which the date column looks like this -

```
14-07-2010  12:18:20
```

but when I click on the cell, the value is shown like this -

```
2010-07-14 12:18:20
```

When I load this file in R, the date looks like this -

```
2010-07-14 12:18:20
```

and the type is given as POSIXct.

How do I convert this POSIXct format **2010-07-14 12:18:20** to

```
14/07/2010 12:18:20
```

this format but keep the type to be POSIXct?

Comment: `?strftime`.....

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Check the link I attached to your Q

Comment: I have already checked that link before posting my question. It didn't help

Comment: `strftime(as.POSIXct('2010-07-14 12:18:20', format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: This return a character type. Is there any way to keep the format as this but make the type as POSIXct?